# Testing the API from the client side

Tags: javascript, testing, tdd, jestjs

I've been working within a project for a couple of months now and met several issues, when the API response changed by the backend guys and it was structured in a way that I didn't expect it to be structured.

The tests that we have mocks the API responses, so they all pass and there is nothing wrong when deploying the app in that state :(

My question is, as I'm quite new to the testing - is it a common thing to do to test the API responses themselves?

If yes - are there any JavaScript libraries that can help me with that?

If no - how to make sure that the response are structured that way we want them to be?

Comment: You need to do INTEGRATION TESTING, not unit testing and you need to let the calls go through. What test framework are you using?

Comment: @CristiMarian Thanks for the fast response! I'm using Jest.

Comment: You can check out this article https://hackernoon.com/api-testing-with-jest-d1ab74005c0a

Comment: I've already read this one. The main flaw is that it mocks the responses, so I can't be sure that the mocked ones equal to the ones from the actual API

Comment: then try this example https://daveceddia.com/snapshot-testing-apis-with-jest/

Comment: @CristiMarian Thank you for this one! I think that this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to add integration tests to test un-mocked API responses.

AND to prevent unexpected API response structure, you should use a versioned API. So as long as you do not upgrade your API version to a new major version, the API response should not be unexpected.

As you are using Jest you can add your integration test using this framework

Answer (score 0):

You can use the documentation lib like **swagger** where you can check the structure of the api response.
Refer: https://swagger.io/solutions/api-documentation/

Comment: That is true, but it required manual work and I want this to be automated